# Are all neural networks today simulated?

Tags: neural-network

Are all modern neural networks simulated or are there physical hardware versions of them in use yet? For example: memristor technology.

Comment: AFAIK, yes.  Apart from the ones inside peoples' heads.  (And even then, can we be sure?) :-)

Comment: I'm a simulation. Aren't you?

Comment: @MitchWheat - So ... you have just FAILed the Turing test :-).

Comment: I believe i don't live in **Matrix**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a Google search revealed these:

- http://phys.org/news/2016-01-scientists-neural-network-plastic-memristors.html
- http://arstechnica.com/science/2015/05/neural-network-chip-built-using-memristors/

So the answer to your question is that physical neural networks using memristors have been built, but I doubt that these examples count as "in use". There is also a good chance that various organizations (e.g. military, commercial) are working on this quietly, and may even have something "in use" behind closed doors.

---

Historically: this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_neural_network) mentions [ADALINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADALINE) which was a physical implementation of neural networks implemented in the 1960s.  It was built using electro-chemical memistors (sic), but the technology did not scale and was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The word for what you're looking for is probably "neuromorphic".  The wikipedia article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromorphic_engineering has a pretty good overview of R&D in the field.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_neural_network

IBM [TrueNorth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueNorth) is likely the closest to a commercial system using this today.